# Bouncing Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

i would like to create animation like below;

[image: ANimation Bounce]

I have used following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
  />


</set>
```

But no able to work out! Any help could be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code

**No need any xml** file in this code for the bounce animation as you want.

**- Up Bouncing Animation**

```
doBounceAnimation(yourView);


private void doBounceAnimation(View targetView) {
        Interpolator interpolator = new Interpolator() {
            @Override
            public float getInterpolation(float v) {
                return getPowOut(v,2);//Add getPowOut(v,3); for more up animation
            }
        };
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationY", 0, 25, 0);
        animator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
        animator.setStartDelay(200);
        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.setRepeatCount(5);
        animator.start();
}

private float getPowOut(float elapsedTimeRate, double pow) {
        return (float) ((float) 1 - Math.pow(1 - elapsedTimeRate, pow));
}
```

**- Down Bouncing Animation**

```
doBounceAnimation(yourView);


private void doBounceAnimation(View targetView) {
        Interpolator interpolator = new Interpolator() {
            @Override
            public float getInterpolation(float v) {
                return getPowIn(v,2);//Add getPowIn(v,3); for more down animation
            }
        };
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "translationY", 0, 25, 0);
        animator.setInterpolator(interpolator);
        animator.setStartDelay(200);
        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.setRepeatCount(5);
        animator.start();
}

private float getPowIn(float elapsedTimeRate, double pow) {
        return (float) Math.pow(elapsedTimeRate, pow);
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: in updated code you don't need to add xml file, without xml file you can create bounce animation.

Comment: i know @hardik but still this is not what i am looking for.

Comment: So,please can you explain what you want I am not understand properly?

Comment: lokk at image arrow pushing up i need this type of animation

Comment: This arrow goes up and down

Comment: So what is the different in I added the animation?

Comment: Please check updated answer may be this is same as you want.

Comment: Please any changes require then tell me

Comment: one quick question what to do if i need animation to push down, like above code is push up now need push down what have to change ?

Answer (score 0):

In Res/anim create this bounce_animation.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true" android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

Then In your Activity class, set the animation to the element you want to tie it to. For example, when the user clicks in the TextView, it will bounce

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val bounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce_animation)

    val textViewToBounce = findViewById(R.id.textViewToBounce)
    textViewToBounce.setOnClickListener {
        textViewToBounce.startAnimation(bounceAnimation)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this one, not same like ! let me try again!

Comment: Sorry this animation have fade in and fade out shade !

Comment: above code  bounces. Anyway, you can use this code too

Comment: ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourTextView, "translationY", -100f, 0f);
animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
animY.setRepeatCount(numRepeats);
animY.start();